Typing Fastify RouteOptions to access queries and reply props
I was trying to use Fastify with typescript in a node project when I was caught in a problem typing the Request and Reply to access on handler function.
This is my code:
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";
import { RouteOptions } from "fastify/types/route";

interface IQuerystring {
  name: string;
}

interface IReply {
  200: { message: string };
}

function endpoint(request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) {
  const { name } = request.query; 
  return reply.code(200).send({ ping: `pong_${name}` });
}

const pingRoute: RouteOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "/ping",
  schema: {
    querystring: { type: "string", proprieties: { name: { type: "string" } } },
  },
  handler: endpoint,
};

export default pingRoute;


The error is on:
const { name } = request.query; // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'

On the docs, from what I understand, there is a way to type with schema, but what i what is to pass to another function both the Request and Reply types.
I already try to type the FastfyRequest and FastifyReply, but the handler rise a error saying that the type don't exist on Fastify Generic Type.
So, what is the best way to type Fastify with typescript in this code.

you can try the following: const { name } = request.query as IQuerystring;
